# How to make check loop result into false by default

Tags: php

I require this loop to set into default to allow for another function into play. How do I set all of the check into false by default?

Example: Making all of this check($checkGeneral) below into `== false` by default.

```
$resultCatAdd = $catCheckA;
$catCheckA = explode(",", $stockrm['einv_stockrm_cat']);
foreach($catCheckA as &$value) {
    if($value == "General Information") {
        $checkGeneral = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Product Information") {
        $checkProduct = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Warranty Information") {
        $checkWarranty = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Sales Parts") {
        $checkSales = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Customer Information") {
        $checkCustomer = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Internal Information") {
        $checkInternal = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Warehouse Information") {
        $checkWarehouse = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Yearly Reset") {
        $checkYR = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logic should be more easy than what you think is a solution, imho (for instance, you could get rid of all those flags). Rethink it from the start :)

Comment: `Switch` and `case` is better than `if`, `else if` and you can define a `default` case as you ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You could make variable names according strings and then set them to false as below:

<?php
$stockrm['einv_stockrm_cat'] = "General Information,Product Information,Warranty Information,Sales Parts,Customer Information,Internal Information,Warehouse Information,Yearly Reset";
$catCheckA = explode(",", $stockrm['einv_stockrm_cat']);
foreach($catCheckA as $key => $value) {
    $varName = explode(" ", $value);
    $check{ucfirst($varName[0])} = false;
}
foreach($catCheckA as &$value) {
    if($value == "General Information") {
        $checkGeneral = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Product Information") {
        $checkProduct = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Warranty Information") {
        $checkWarranty = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Sales Parts") {
        $checkSales = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Customer Information") {
        $checkCustomer = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Internal Information") {
        $checkInternal = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Warehouse Information") {
        $checkWarehouse = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Yearly Reset") {
        $checkYearly = true;
    }
}
```